# Decrease stock when order is complete Magento

Tags: magento, inventory, stock

Magento by default decrease stock when order is placed, but i need decrease stock just when an order is completed or processing.

how can I do it?

Please Help.

Comment: i have do this....put the code tomorrow

Comment: thanks if you could too send it to webdecolombia@gmail.com I'll so grateful

Comment: Hi @AmitBera , can you paste here the code for decreasing stock only at shipping or processing? This can help lot of people here. Thanks!